# Custom Search API not returning all results

Tags: google-custom-search, google-apis-explorer

I am a long time customer of using the Custom Search API.

The problem - as described in the CSE documentation - is that the API is intended to search your own site and not the web in general.  It misses results, for example from books.google.com, and results from other languages etc.

Is there another (paid) API that returns all results?

Sample search string: "الاستخدامات التالية من التطبيق"

(The above search gets 1 result in Google Search but 0 results in the Custom Search I am paying for.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to switch to Bing, but I was getting better results in the end.

For anyone else having this issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v7-reference